# H tags in CKEditor

Tags: seo, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I was simply wondering if there's an easy way of creating H tags through CKEditor (without going to HTML view) ?

I need this in order for SEO as well as making the content nicer to read by breaking it up.

One would have thought there's a button on the toolbar for this but no :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Format dropdown allows you to select such options.

You can also customize the Styles dropdown or create a new plugin if you want each option available as a toolbar button, [this is a sample of such plugin](http://blog.lystor.org.ua/2010/11/ckeditor-plugin-and-toolbar-button-for.html).